# How to stop when moving a face other faces change too (In edit mode)

Tags: edit-mode

Im editing 3 faces. However, the ones that are near to them get affected too. I want to not affect them.
[image: Green: What i want it to be Red: What i don't want it to be]

As you see below, the red line is what i don't want to happen.
Basically. When im changing the 3 faces, i don't want the faces near them be affected.

Comment: instead create a loopcut (Ctrl R) and remove the faces you don't want?

Comment: I used split instead

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question (and as @moonboots says):

<kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> to create a loopcut and move it to the height you need. Then go into <kbd>Face</kbd> mode with <kbd>3</kbd>, select the 3 faces and <kbd>X</kbd> to delete them.

[image]